VBA Button to put formula in multiple cell
I'm looking for some way to put an xlookup into multiple cells using VBA with a button.
This is what I have tried
Sub RSPK()
    
    Range("E18").Select
    ' Selecting Minta column
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=XLOOKUP(B18;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!B15:B1030;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!Q15:Q1030;0;0)"
    
    Range("E19").Select
    ' Selecting Kirim column
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=XLOOKUP(B18;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!B15:B1030;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!R15:R1030;0;0)"
    
    Range("E20").Select
    ' Selecting ED column
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=XLOOKUP(B18;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!B15:B1030;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!S15:S1030;0;0)"
    
    Range("E21").Select
    ' Selecting HARGA column
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=XLOOKUP(B18;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!B15:B1030;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!U15:U1030;0;0)"
    
    Range("E22").Select
    ' Selecting KET column
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=XLOOKUP(B18;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!B15:B1030;'DISTRIBUSI OKTOBER 2024'!T15:T1030;0;0)"

End Sub

But it's not working and the error code is

And the error is here

Any idea on how to improve the code? Thank you in advance!

Please check if Activesheet is protected. You don't need to use Select. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=2

Two issues here: '.Formula' requires US English  format.  That includes using ',' rather than ';'.  If you prefer to use your local dialect, use '.FormulaLocal'.  Also, '.Formula' requires 'A1' format.  If you want to specify ranges as 'R1C1' format use '.FormulaR1C1̀'

Stop using .Select from VBA. You don't need to select a cell to work with it. See this post.
